# Error module 'jsonpath' has no attribute 'jsonpath' displayed for below code

Tags: python, api, pytest

Getting  **AttributeError: module 'jsonpath' has no attribute 'jsonpath'** for below python code.
I am using pytest framework. 
I have googled it a lot still not able to resolve this.Please can someone help me to resolve this error

```
import requests
import ssl
import jsonpath


def test_result_api():
    token_url = "https://XXX/oauth/token"
    data = {'grant_type': 'password', 'username': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'password': '12345*'}
    response = requests.post(token_url, data)
    # print(response.text)
    token_value = jsonpath.jsonpath(response.json(), 'access_token')
```

Comment: I believe the jsonpath library for Python is `jsonpath_rw`. So:

`from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath` perhaps?

Comment: what do you get if you `print(dir(jsonpath))`? I have a function `jsonpath` after installing with pip.

Comment: Got path like 
C:\Users\<username>\<projectname>\<directoryname>

Comment: This is an unusual location - how did you install `jsonpath`? Did you use `pip install jsonpath` or something else? Also - maybe there is an additional module or file `jsonpath` at that location - in this case try to remove or rename this, if that is the case..

Comment: Is it a module you wrote yourself? Or did you name your private module `jsonpath.py` so it clashes with the installed `jsonpath` package? Run `python -c "import jsonpath; print(jsonpath.__file__)"` and show the directory stucture this file is in.